# C++ trouble reading txt file

Tags: c++

I can't read a txt file.  I've tried with different pieces of code which should work and with different text files.  The problem isn't that I got the wrong name (the file doesn't lack a txt or have an extra txt).  Also, adding a second backwards slash \ or replacing it with forwards slash / doesn't fix it.

Here is the code:

```
// ConsoleApplication74.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int x;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("C:\Users\chaim\SkyDrive\Documents\string\text1.txt");
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1); // terminate with error
    }

    while (inFile >> x) {
        sum = sum + x;
    }

    inFile.close();
    cout << "Sum = " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain, as completely as possible, what your program does and how that is different from what is desired.

Comment: I recommend using `/` in your filenames, because `\t` is a tab character.

Comment: Even if you really like header files, there is no need to include them more than once.

Comment: Get rid of `stdafx` and turn off *precompiled headers* for small programs.  The precompiled header feature does not give you any advantages unless you have a huge program with lots of include files or you are writing a Windows program and accessing their API. *(The windows.h file is huge and could benefit from being precompiled.)*

Answer (score 1):

`"C:\Users\chaim\SkyDrive\Documents\string\text1.txt"` should be `"C:\\Users\\chaim\\SkyDrive\\Documents\\string\\text1.txt"`. That way you get backslashes at the appropriate places in the file name.